# ListCtrl to adjust window in wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython

I've been creating an app using wxPython. I'd like to display some data using ListCtrl and I'd like the colums occuping maximum space. This is: the maximum size available is divided between the rows I have. I've tried this but it doesn't work (this is the panel where listctrl is):

```
class VirtualListPanel(wx.Panel):
   def __init__(self, parent):
    wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, -1)

    width = self.GetParent().GetClientSize().width/5
    coches = vehiculos()    
    gris = wx.Color(220,220,220)

    self.lista = wx.ListCtrl(self, style=wx.LC_REPORT|wx.LC_HRULES|wx.LC_VRULES)
    self.lista.InsertColumn(0, "Matricula", width=width)
    self.lista.InsertColumn(1, "Tipo", width=width)
    self.lista.InsertColumn(2, "Matriculacion", width=width)
    self.lista.InsertColumn(3, "Ult. ITV", width=width)
    self.lista.InsertColumn(4, "Prox. ITV", width=width)

    i = 0   
    for data in coches:
        index = self.lista.InsertStringItem(i, data[0])
            self.lista.SetStringItem(index, 1, str(data[1]))
            self.lista.SetStringItem(index, 2, str(data[2]))
        self.lista.SetStringItem(index, 3, str(data[3]))
        self.lista.SetStringItem(index, 4, str(prox(data[1],data[2],data[3])))
        if((index+1) % 2 == 0):
            self.lista.SetItemBackgroundColour(index,gris)
        i += 1

    self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    self.sizer.Add(self.lista, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL)
    self.SetSizer(self.sizer)

    self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.OnResize)

def OnResize(self, event):
        width = self.GetParent().GetClientSize().width/5
    self.lista.SetColumnWidth(0, width)
    self.lista.SetColumnWidth(1, width)
    self.lista.SetColumnWidth(2, width)
    self.lista.SetColumnWidth(3, width)
    self.lista.SetColumnWidth(4, width)
```

Now, it doesn't even occupy full window, it only shows a small square on top left corner. If I comment "self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE..." line, it shows full screen, but columns are small.

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve here: do you want to auto align column widths or the list widget itself? Could you provide a bigger example? Maybe the problem is with how you add the VirtualListPanel to a sizer? You could try the wx.lib.mixins.inspection.InspectionMixin to investigate layout.

Comment: What I want is to have columns adjusted to full size. This means, if the window is 1000px width, I'd like to have each col as 1000/5px width (I now have 5 cols), and if the window is resized, columns resize too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are missing is `event.Skip()` call in the `OnResize` function. Some details about event propagation can be found here http://wiki.wxpython.org/EventPropagation. Alternatively you could use `self.Layout()`.

Comment: OMG! That simple line made me a headache!!! Thank you very much! It now works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest that you look into ObjectListView (http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/python/). This is a wrapper around ListCtrl that has this and many other nice features builtin.
In your case, you could just pass the `isSpaceFilling=True` parameter to every column and they would divide the space equally. You can even set a minimum width for each column.

```
ColumnDefn('Title', valueGetter='title', isSpaceFilling=True, minimumWidth=100)
```

I know ObjectListView looks a bit confusing at first, but I found it very usefull.

Comment: I'd like to learn how to do it in wxPython because I think the problem is me, not the library itself, but thanks anyway!